# Kaggle can not find my tesseract file however my code works on VS code what should I do?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Here is a simple example that I work on Kaggle. When I run the code it says "TesseractNotFoundError: C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information." However when I try to run the code on Visual Studio Code it works properly. What might be the problem ?

```
    import pytesseract
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract- 
    OCR/tesseract.exe'
    import cv2
    img = cv2.imread("/kaggle/input/pictures/cuma1.jpeg")
    text_data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print(text_data)
```

Comment: Why did you specified `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` in Kagle? I assume it does not exist and expecting that Kagle is running on Windows is quite strange ;-)

Comment: As you say I didn't need to specify that when I run my code on VsCode I assumed I also need to write in Kaggle thanks for your reply :)